# Accessing two different Rails environments from a single Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a Rake task that will retrieve data stored in the databases of two different Rails apps, with different Ruby and gem versions. What I have so far is

```
task :get_data do                                                                                                                                                            
  puts `/<path>/<to>/<first>/<app>/bin/rails runner 'FirstDataRetriever.new.as_set'`
  puts `/<path>/<to>/<second>/<app>/bin/rails runner 'SecondDataRetriever.new.as_set'`                                                              
end
```

The problem is that Rails runner is trying to execute the `DataRetriever` classes using the Ruby version of the Rakefile, which is in a separate repo using different infrastructure.

Both the `DataRetriever` classes make use of `ActiveRecord` models in each app, so they must be run in the Rails environment of each app, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can specify Ruby version in `.ruby-version` [file](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects) inside of root directory of your projects if you are using RVM or rbenv.
2. You can specify Rails environment use `RAILS_ENV` environment variable i.e. `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails runner ...`

I hope it can help to solve your problems.